# Play Video which is stored in a MariaDB as BLOB-File

Tags: php, html, database, video, blob

With the attached script I'm trying to play a video which is stored in a database as a BLOB-File. The variable `$row['video']` contains the video as BLOB-Dataformat. Everything is working very well until I try to play a video in a different dataformat than mp4.
I know that the video-tag in HTML5 doesn't allow *.avi, etc., so I also tried `<embed>` and `<object>`. Both are also only working for mp4. Do you have any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Jump to "README" below to find the location within the code, where the problem occurs.

This is an assignment for school, so it's necessary to work with the BLOB-dataformat.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
  <?php
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['id']);    

    if($id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM video WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result) 
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

            if(checkFileFormat($row["videoformat"]) == "image")
            {
                //display photo
                echo '<img width="25%" height="25%" src="data:image/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,'.base64_encode($row['video']).'"/>
                      <br>';
                echo $row["title"] . "<br><br>";

                echo '
                    <object width="368" height="119" data="data:' . checkFileFormat($row["videoformat"]) . '/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'"></object>
                ';

            }
            else if(checkFileFormat($row["videoformat"]) == "video")
            {
                //display video        
/* 
************* README ************* 
base64 encode + video tag --> works for mp4-videos; I don't have any clue how to play for example avi-videos. I already tried via <object> and  <embed> both also does not work for me.
************* END README ************* 
*/
        //base64 encode + video tag *** does work for mp4
        echo '
            video: <br>
            <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="data:video/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'" type="video/' . $row["videoformat"] .'">
            </video>
            <br><br>';

        //embed for avi file *** does not work
        echo '
            embed for avi: <br>
            <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="data:video/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'">
            </embed>
            <br><br>
        ';

        //object for avi file *** does not work
        echo '
            object for avi: <br>
            <object type="video/x-msvideo" data="data:video/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'">
                <param name="src" value="data:video/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'">
                <param name="autoStart" value="0">
            </object>
            <br><br>
        ';

        //object for mp4 file *** does work
        echo '
            object for mp4: <br>
            <object type="video/mp4" data="data:video/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'">
            </object>
            <br><br>
        ';

        //embed for mp4 file *** does work
        echo '
            embed for mp4: <br>
            <embed type="video/mp4" src="data:video/' . $row["videoformat"] . ';base64,' . base64_encode($row['video']).'">
            </embed>
            <br><br>
        ';


                echo "Title: " . $row["title"] . " | Duration: " . $row["duration"] . " | Format: " . $row["videoformat"];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error: file format not supported!";
            }
        }
        else    
        {
            trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . $conn->error);
        }
    }
    else
        echo "Error: missing id";

    ?>
```

Comment: Browsers only support mp4 no matter how you embed it.

Comment: really? is that a fact? isn't there any possibility to play *.avi, etc. with modern browsers? (btw. edited the post to show you some attempts for embedding, playing an mp4 works in every case, other file formats are not possible)

Comment: Well, webm is supported in most browsers too. But no browser supports avi.

Comment: good to know that this is not possible - that solves the problem for me - thanks so much :-)